# Is it possible to keep track of changes to tables structure?

Tags: mysql

Is it somehow possible to keep track of changes made to the STRUCTURE (not the data) made to tables?

I mean, i don't want to know when rows are inserted/updated/deleted, what i want is to know **when** the table *definition* is been changed (and **what** those changes were). E.g. to know if/when a column was added, removed, if a column type was changed, if an index was added, etc.

In other words, to keep track of all the "ALTERS" of the tables. (and the state before those alters)

I'd like this to know exactly when some changes were made, and to keep track of discrepancies of data, for example to know when a column was changed to hold `VARCHAR`s instead of `INT`s (just an idea), or when a new column was added, etc.

So is there a way to do this?

I am using MySQL, version 5.1.66. And, if it is not possible in MySQL, is it in other Databases?

Thanks

Comment: In SQL-Server, you can do this using [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: In a disciplined development environment, you'd use your version control system--subversion, mercurial, git, even RCS in a pinch.